# sql netezza case when, how to use a temporal variable?

Tags: case, netezza

How can i make this kind of CASE WHEN in Netezza:

```
select
  case A+B+C
  when 0 then 1
  else A+B+C
end
FROM X
```

the idea is not to write again A+B+C like this

```
select
  case 's' = A+B+C
  when 0 then 1
  else 's'
end
FROM X
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Netezza, you can use the following syntax to avoid repeating the expression A+B+C in your CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A+B+C = 0 THEN 1 ELSE A+B+C END FROM X;
```

This will check if the sum of A, B, and C is equal to 0. If it is, then it will return 1. Otherwise, it will return the sum of A, B, and C.

You can also use a subquery to calculate the sum of A, B, and C and then use it in the CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sum_abc = 0 THEN 1 ELSE sum_abc END
FROM (
  SELECT A+B+C as sum_abc
  FROM X
) subquery;
```

This will first calculate the sum of A, B, and C in the subquery and then use it in the outer query's CASE statement.

Comment: thank you!, I´m going in that way but I was looking for something more elegant, without subqueries